# Using Subversion with IIS on a Windows Virtual Machine

Tags: svn, iis

I am thinking about installing subversion on a windows Virtual Machine that is hosted elsewhere and do not want to install apache.

Am I limited to access it using the svn: protocol? Does it work well offsite?

Any body has any experience with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is the problem that installing Apache creates other issues or is it that you don't want to have to manage the installation process?

If the latter then I'd suggest using [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/) which is a single package install that makes things a lot easier!

Comment: VistualSVN Server installs a barebones apache server, if I recall correctly.

Comment: @Malfist - It does indeed which is why I wrote the answer the way I did

Comment: The problem is that this is a production server and I am worried that installing apache may screw things up with port conflict etc.

Comment: Ah - VisualSVN server allows you to specify the ports as part of the installation process. It used to use ports (8080, 8443) that were probably safe by default, now it uses the default web server ports by default (which is not what you want in this case) but, as I say, you can override those. My last install was onto a production W2k8 server...

Answer (score 2):

One option is VisualSVN.

http://www.visualsvn.com/server/

This package installs and configures Apache for you, and is very easy to install and administer.

If you're ok with running Apache but just don't want the hassle of installing and configuring Apache, this package might be right for you.

Comment: I am wondering if we could avoid apache altogether. As far as I know subversion is a file based repository and http is a medium of communication with the repository so theoritically IIS should be able to server the request. Or am I wrong?